# How can I read the URL parameter in a Perl CGI program?

Tags: perl, cgi, uri

How can I read the URL parameter in a Perl CGI program?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a goto for many, and Google's "I feel lucky" points here for several searches.  So these comments above are useless noise and beg for stackexchange to add downvoting for comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For **GET requests**, [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) parses the specified parameters and makes them available via the `param()` method.

For **POST requests**, `param()` will return the parameters from the postdata, but any parameters specified via a query string in the URL itself are still available from the `url_param()` method.   (This is can be helpful when a POST request is larger than `$CGI::POST_MAX`; in that case, CGI just discards the postdata, but you can arrange to have query string parameters that identify what kind of request it was to provide a good error message.)

For **ISINDEX style requests**, the keywords requested are available via the `keywords()` method, as well as via `param()` in a faux "keywords" parameter.

**Update:** in case you meant something other than the parameters by "URL Parameter", the `url()` method provides all or parts of the requested URL; see [OBTAINING THE SCRIPT'S URL](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI.pm#OBTAINING_THE_SCRIPT%27S_URL).

Answer (score 5):

It's recommended that you use a URL parser such as mentioned by ysth, but if you REALLY want the raw input, it's available through the following:

for GET:

```
$contents = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
```

for POST:

```
$contents = <STDIN>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try thus code:

```
my @names = $query->param;
foreach $name ( @names ) {
    if (  $name =~ /\_/ ) { 
        next;
    } else {
        print "<p> ".$name."\t=\t".$query->param($name) . "</p>\n";
    }
}
```