# how to get value from java script function to perl

Tags: perl

I want to  get the value of check box selected and pass it to a query for deleting the value from database.
java script code

```
function deleteRows(){

isTable = document.getElementById('dataTbl');
nBoxes = document.getElementsByName('delBox');
for (i=nBoxes.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
if (nBoxes[i].checked === true)
{
var a =nBoxes[i].value;


alert("Do you want to delete this row?"+a);
isTable.deleteRow(i+1);
}
}
}
```

i need the **var a** value in perl so that i can pass it to the delete query and delete the selected row.

html code

```
<Table id='dataTbl' border='1' >
<tr>
<td><input type=checkbox name='delBox' value=@data></td> 
<td bgcolor=#0099FF>$pid</td>
<td bgcolor=#99CCFF>$project_name</td>
<td bgcolor=#3399FF> $variant_no</td>
<td bgcolor=#99CCFF> $variant_name</td>
<td bgcolor=#3399FF>$vehicle_class</td>
<td bgcolor=#99CCFF> $vc_no</td>
</table>
<input type=button value="Delete Rows" onclick="deleteRows()" id="delbtn">
```

perl query

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("delete form table name col1,col2,col3 where id='$a'"); 
$sth->execute() or die "$!";
```

Comment: You need to send that variable through POST or another HTTP request. Keep in mind that JS code executes in browser while Perl executes in server. And btw [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) incoming...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you explain in more precised form.

Comment: I think it's clear enough. If you didn't understand then I suggest you read more about HTTP client/server communication, you're lacking basic concepts like POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do POST request (or DELETE to be precise) towards server where your perl script runs.

e.g.

After you get a variable set (let's say you are using jquery):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url, // where your script lives
  data: {'a' : a},
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  }
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

in your script you will then get 'a' variable from post request.

Answer (score 0):

Sample scenario:

1. JS working on Your Client PC. Users selected some id.
2. JS sends selected id to server side Perl CGI script.
3. Perl parses GET request get id.
4. Perl checks if id is number not some string to hack your server.
5. Perl executes delete in MySQL.

Resourses:
JS send GET request with Param:
[HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Perl Read GET Parameter
[How can I read the URL parameter in a Perl CGI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996698/how-can-i-read-the-url-parameter-in-a-perl-cgi-program)

Perl MySQL Tutorial:
http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/perlmysql_3.htm