# How to receive parameters and values from POST method in Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, cgi

Is there **any way** to retrieve the parameters and values using POST method?

```
http://hostname/cgi-bin/params?name1=value1&name2=value2&;..
```

I need to write a **CGI script** to receive the parameters and values using **`POST`** method from the below url.

```
Host: hostname.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Please help me to do this.

Comment: @choroba I want to write the CGI script to receive parameters from the url.

Comment: @Vasanth: POST messages don't have a query field in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are in the URL, it's GET, not POST.

For GET:
[How can I read the URL parameter in a Perl CGI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996698/how-can-i-read-the-url-parameter-in-a-perl-cgi-program)

For POST:
[how to get POST values in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088538/how-to-get-post-values-in-perl)